# Extending class template

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates

How would I do to extend a template class, for example vector? The below code does not work. The compiler whines about 'Vector' not being a template.

```
template <typename T>
class Vector<T> : public std::vector<T>
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't inherit from the standard library containers. They're not designed for that. For example, they don't have virtual destructors, so if you're not careful, your code will break when your derived vectors are destroyed.

Answer (score 19):

Your syntax is wrong; you need to use:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector : public std::vector<T>
```

That said, you should not extend the standard library containers via inheritance, if for no other reason then because they do not have virtual destructors and it is therefore inherently unsafe.

If you want to "enhance" `std::vector`, do so using composition (i.e., with a member variable of `std::vector` type) or use non-member functions to provide your additional functionality.

Comment: But is it OK to inherit from STL Containers if you have no virtual members?

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with extending another class. The problem is *your own* derived class.

You define a class template like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
...
```

and not

```
template <typename T>
class Vector<T>
{
...
```

Comment: jalfi is right: class Vector<T> is Java syntax, not C++ syntax.

Comment: It's the syntax for a specialization, hence the compiler expects to have seen a base template for `Vector`.